# Angular 1.4 parse contents of ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

What am I doing?

**Briefly:** I have an array of objects called $scope.myData and a string called $scope.layout. What I want to do is have a span with `ng-repeat="x in myData"` and also `ng-bind-html="layout"`. Layout has `{{ x.key }}` in several spots. I want it to load the layout, then start displaying it for each object in the array, and fill in the variables.

**More specifically:** I'm loading the data and the layout through AJAX (using jQuery). I'm not sure if this matters at all, since everything else works fine.

**What code do I have so far?**

I'm including angular-sanitize.js to unsanitize my HTML in the `$scope.layout` variable. I also added `ngSanitize` to the `app=angular.module()` declaration.

Under the AJAX stuff, you really only need to read the stuff within `if(status=='success'){}` since that part works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.doit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            data:{'ajax':true},
            url:'<?=URL('--url to load from--')?>'
        }).always(function(data,status){
            if(status=='success'){
                var getelementby='[ng-app="myApp"]';
                window.data=data;
                angular.element(document.querySelector(getelementby)).scope().$apply(function($scope){
                    $scope.layout=window.data.layout;
                    $scope.myData=window.data.data;
                });
            }else{
                console.log('Error :(');
            }
        });
    });
});

var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){$scope.myData={};});
</script>

<a href="#" class="doit btn btn-default">Load</a>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <span ng-repeat="x in myData"><span ng-bind-html="layout"></span></span>
</div>
```

(I know my error checking is crude so far)

**What does it do?** It displays the layout the correct amount of times, but it does NOT fill in the `{{ x.key }}` expressions.

What could I be doing wrong? I'm already unsanitizing my HTML. Is this just not how angular works? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery ajax with angular. Try using services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I think you're doing it not the 'AngularJS way'. With Angular you should reduce jQuery usage to a mimimum. The best is to never use it. For basic apps you don't need it at all. (If you need jQuery add it in a directive.) You shouldn't load views with ajax requests like you tried. You should use a router for this. Please have a look at the docs of [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: I was using jQuery ajax because I'm using jQuery's click() function, and I'm not sure how to use $http when inside of a function

Comment: @AWolf thanks for your input. As I said in another comment, this was just an attempt to add a thin angular layer to a mostly-backend project, but I see now that I just don't understand how angular is meant to be used well enough to justify adding it at the end like this. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You should not load an angular template via ng-bind-html.

Instead of this:

```
// controller 
$scope.templ = '{{ x }}';

// template 
<div ng-bind-html="templ"></div>
```

Move the template to its own directive:

```
// someDirective.js
angular.module('my.module').directive('myTemplate', function () {
  return {
    template: '{{ x }}'
  };
});
```

And use that directive in your original template:

```
<some-directive />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Honestly I was intending to add a lightweight angular layer to a mostly backend project, but at this point I obviously don't understand angular well enough to be trying this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the function in the controller to do the same thing that you are trying to do using jQuery.
Here is some code that should work.

```js
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){

  $scope.myData={};

$scope.getAjaxData = function(){

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data:{'ajax':true},
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.myData = response.data;  

      }, function errorCallback(response) {

            console.log('error');
      });

  }

}]);
```

Then in your HTML try to display the data using something like the following...

```
<a ng-click="getAjaxData()" class="doit btn btn-default">Load</a>
<span ng-repeat="x in myData">
  <p ng-bind="x.key"></p>
  <p ng-bind="x.value"></p>
</span>
```

This is just a rough example. Try it and see if it works.

Thanks,
Paras